# Ruby weirdness: x == y && [x, y].uniq == [x, y]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, activesupport

I have an two-element array of ActiveRecord objects, `slots_to_import`. These objects have `begin_at` columns, and thus attributes. I was trying to get objects that have unique `begin_at` values. Alas, `slots_to_import.uniq_by(&:begin_at)` did not work. But the `begin_at` values are equal for the two objects:

```
(rdb:1) p slots_to_import.first.begin_at == slots_to_import.last.begin_at
true
(rdb:1) p slots_to_import.uniq_by(&:begin_at).map(&:begin_at)
[Mon, 26 Nov 2012 19:00:00 UTC +00:00, Mon, 26 Nov 2012 19:00:00 UTC +00:00]
(rdb:1) p [slots_to_import.first.begin_at, slots_to_import.last.begin_at].uniq
[Mon, 26 Nov 2012 19:00:00 UTC +00:00, Mon, 26 Nov 2012 19:00:00 UTC +00:00]
```

Some more checking around:

```
(rdb:1) p [slots_to_import.first.begin_at.to_datetime, slots_to_import.last.begin_at.to_datetime].uniq
[Mon, 26 Nov 2012 19:00:00 +0000]
(rdb:1) p [slots_to_import.first.begin_at.usec, slots_to_import.last.begin_at.usec].uniq
[0]
(rdb:1) p [slots_to_import.first.begin_at.to_f, slots_to_import.last.begin_at.to_f].uniq
[1353956400.0]
(rdb:1) p [slots_to_import.first.begin_at.utc, slots_to_import.last.begin_at.utc].uniq
[Mon, 26 Nov 2012 19:00:00 +0000]
(rdb:1) p [slots_to_import.first.begin_at, slots_to_import.last.begin_at].uniq
[Mon, 26 Nov 2012 19:00:00 UTC +00:00, Mon, 26 Nov 2012 19:00:00 UTC +00:00]
```

I thought perhaps that uniq was checking whether they were the same object (since they were not). But no, some noodling in my rails console showed me that it does not use an object id check:

```
1.8.7 :111 > x = Time.zone.parse("Mon, 29 Oct 2012 19:29:17 UTC +00:00")
 => Mon, 29 Oct 2012 19:29:17 UTC +00:00 
1.8.7 :112 > y = Time.zone.parse("Mon, 29 Oct 2012 19:29:17 UTC +00:00")
 => Mon, 29 Oct 2012 19:29:17 UTC +00:00 
1.8.7 :113 > x == y
 => true 
1.8.7 :114 > [x, y].uniq
 => [Mon, 29 Oct 2012 19:29:17 UTC +00:00]
```

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7p358 and ActiveSupport 3.2.0. BTW, I can solve my own issue by simply adding a `to_datetime`, but I'm really curious why this isn't working without a conversion.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the results of `x.hash` and `y.hash`?

Comment: @hammar: That's an interesting idea seeing as `uniq_by` is Hash based.

Comment: @hammar `x.hash` and `y.hash` are also equal! - `(rdb:1) p slots_to_import.first.begin_at.hash == slots_to_import.last.begin_at.hash
=> true`

Comment: Would it be possible to get enough data and code to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Maybe I can come up with a minimal test case. Right now, the only way I can reproduce it is with a debugger statement in the middle of an application.

Answer (score 1):

I thought you were working with plain `Time` objects, so I started by looking at `time.c` from the Ruby platform source (1.9.3). If they were Ruby 1.9.3 `Time` objects, you could try:

```
[x.to_r, y.to_r]
```

Now I know you're working with `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` objects. (As a suggestion, it would be good to mention key information like this next time you post a question.) Here is the body of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#eql?`:

```
def eql?(other)
  utc == other
end
```

And here is the hash  function:

```
alias :hash, :to_i
```

So the next step is for you to show what you get from `[x.utc, y.utc, x.to_i, y.to_i, x.utc.class, y.utc.class]`.

Comment: Is this for ruby 1.8.7p358? I'm getting `NoMethodError: undefined method \`to_r'` if I do `Time.now.to_r`. Also, these particular `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` objects are backed by `DateTime` objects, which are also missing the `to_r` method.

Comment: I was looking at the source for Ruby 1.9.3. If I have time I might look at the Ruby 1.8 source... in the meantime try `to_f` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I did already do a `to_f` check and included that in the original question - they are equal in that regard as well.

Comment: I just saw your edits. I checked `x.utc` and `y.utc`. They are equal and `[x.utc, y.utc].uniq` indeed gives you back just one rather than two objects in the array (this is in the original question btw). The classes returned by `x.utc` and `y.utc` are both `DateTime`. `[x, y].uniq` still has both objects which are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Different microseconds is my guess. 2 objects can show the same inspect string but not be equal.

Comment: You're right about the inspect string, but wrong about microseconds. You'll note that I check with the `usec` method in my question. Quote: `(rdb:1) p [slots_to_import.first.begin_at.usec, slots_to_import.last.begin_at.usec].uniq
=> [0]`

Comment: Also, I don't think two datetimes/times with different microseconds will be == to each other: `1.8.7 :006 > Time.now == Time.now
 => false`

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):017:0> x = 'a'
=> "a"
irb(main):018:0> y = 'a'
=> "a"
irb(main):019:0> x == y
=> true
irb(main):020:0> [x,y].uniq
=> ["a"]
irb(main):021:0> x.object_id == y.object_id
=> false
irb(main):024:0> x.hash == y.hash
=> true
```

Ruby equality test is based on value, not reference. If you want to compare if they are referencing to the same object, you should compare `o.object_id`

Comment: I care about value, not reference. In your snippet, the values are equal, and the `uniq` reflects that. In mine, the values are equal, but the uniq doesn't reflect that.